# Crash when moving mails from Outlook.com to IMAP

Tags: email, imap, microsoft-outlook-2016

In my Outlook (Office 365, Version 1705 Build 8201.2102 Click and Go) I have set up multiple IMAP accounts and one Outlook.com ActiveSync account.

For some weeks now I have the following issue:
When I move an email from my outlook.com inbox to an imap inbox outlook crashes. After this crash outlook crashes everytime I start it. The only temporary fix here is to remove the imap account I moved the mail to and recreate it in outlook.
After this fix outlook freezes once but works afterwards.

Note: The email I moved like this is lost and is gone from the old inbox and nowhere to be found in the inbox I wanted to move it to.

**Important:**
It seems to only happen with some mails. I sent me a short test email and could move it normally without issues. I then moved a normal mail I received and it happened again...

I also tried to start outlook in safe mode but it crashes anyway.

PS: Moving an email from IMAP to outlook.com works.

Thanks

**EDIT info for IMAP accounts:**
Encryption is enabled SSL/TLS.
Root folder path is set to: INBOX

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. And Microsoft are working on the fix. Just wait for the coming updates, or closely monitor the below threads:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c21f2dad-7b2a-4e0f-ae19-9e4ced66132b/outlook-2016-constantly-crashing-microsoft-outlook-has-stopped-working?forum=outlook

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/de7ca6dd-ebef-4201-bc03-36bb1207b8fc/outlook-2016-crashes-every-30-sec-since-june-22-exchange-amp-imap-account-not-compatible?forum=outlook